# Vue3 child components' refs do not return exposed properties when async functions are called inside script setup

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am rendering some dynamic components and giving each of them a ref so that I can retrieve child components' `model` property later.

```
<component :is="getFormComponentByType(kycBuilder[key].type, key)"
           :ref="el => kycRefs[key] = el">
</component>
```

This is my parent component:

```
const kycRefs = {}

// init kycRefs for each value in kycBuilder array
function setKycRefs() {
    Object.keys(kycBuilder.value).forEach(key => {
        kycRefs[key] = ref(null)
    })
}

setKycRefs()

// Get child components so I can render them dynamically
function getFormComponentByType(type, key) {
    switch (type) {
        case 'text':
            return defineAsyncComponent(() => import('../../components/formComponents/LongText.vue'))
        case 'boolean':
            return defineAsyncComponent(() => import('../../components/formComponents/Switch.vue'))
        // ...
        default:
            return 'div'
    }
}
```

This is my child component.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input v-model="model" type="text" :placeholder="id">
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
    data: String,
    id: String
})

const model = ref(props.data)

defineExpose({
    model
})
</script>
```

Then I retrieve `model` in parent like this:

```
for (const key of Object.keys(kycRefs)) {
     console.log(key, kycRefs[key])
}
```

This works fine, the output is:

[image: Expected output]

Vue debugging tool also shows my `model`:

[image: Vue debugging tool]

However, I have async calls in some of my components like so:

```
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
    data: String
})

const model = ref(props.data)
const options = ref([])
await getOptions()

async function getOptions() {
    // call to api
}

defineExpose({
    model
})
</script>
```

This returns something different. `data` seems to be the child component's props. I can't find my `model` property.

[image: Proxy object returned]

This is what Vue debugging console shows. Instead of giving an `Object`, it identifies my component's file name `Nationality` and says it's a `component instance` and shows a lot more stuff.

[image]

So then I can't get my `model`.

I found a work around by putting my async calls inside `onBeforeMounted` lifecycle, then the component successfully returns `model` like other components. But I don't see what's going on here.

I am using Nuxt `3.6.3`. Could someone help me with this? Thanks a lot!